# Running Tomcat Maven plugin with added project provided dependency

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, maven-3, maven-plugin

Need to be pointed in the right direction on this perhaps, but if I add a "provided" dependency that is not included in the tomcat set of provided dependencies, running `tomcat7:run` from within eclipse fails with a `classnotfoundexception` on the class from the provided scope jar.

It needs to "provided" because it's a custom jar from a separate project that I've run mvn install on and for production am copying the jar to the $CATALINA_BASE/shared directory so that it's available (as a singleton) across applications/webapps.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>IndexFileAccessTracker</groupId>
        <artifactId>IndexFileAccessTracker</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Only way I see (with my limited knowledge of Maven and the Tomcat7 plugin) is to change the scope to `compile` when running tomcat from the plugin in Eclipse and then change the scope back to `provided` when running the `package` goal.

Are there solutions to this? I tried adding the dependency to the the tomcat maven plugin (keeping the main maven dependency as `provided` but got the same class not found error:

```
            <!-- For Maven Tomcat Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/CounterWebApp</path>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>IndexFileAccessTracker</groupId>
                    <artifactId>IndexFileAccessTracker</artifactId>
                    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Again, it needs to be `provided` in the main Maven dependency because I don't want it included in the deployed WAR.

Comment: Remove <scope>compile</scope> from the dependency under the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by using profiles, similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/5951630

```
...
</dependencies>
<profiles>
<profile>
    <id>runineclipse</id>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>IndexFileAccessTracker</groupId>
            <artifactId>IndexFileAccessTracker</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</profile>  
</profiles>
<build>
...
```

Then in my run/debug configuration just added `runineclipse` to the `Profiles:` box.
(On a side note, to do step through debugging I had to manually add the project to the Source tab.)

The build configuration was just the same `package` in the `Goals:` box; and I left the original dependency to have scope `provided`.

Answer (score 0):

The [tomcat7-maven-plugin](https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html) and its `run` goal

> Requires dependency resolution of artifacts in scope: test

Everythig that is on the compile classpath is also on the test classpath.
Thats why it is working with scope `compile`.

So the solution in your case would be to mark your dependency as `test` what even is (imo) semantically correct.

This will make the library available at local test-time, but not in the final artifact.

Comment: seems to only work in compile. I tried changing to test and still get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.awgtek.indextracker.HtmlPageFilter
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass when doing tomcat:run

Comment: I checked the source code of the tomcat plugin and found a flag that [is named *useTestClasspath*](https://github.com/apache/tomcat-maven-plugin/blob/trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Forg%2Fapache%2Ftomcat%2Fmaven%2Fplugin%2Ftomcat7%2Frun%2FRunMojo.java#L109) . Thats a bit weird as seems to contradict the [plugins header definition to use always the test-classpath](https://github.com/apache/tomcat-maven-plugin/blob/trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Forg%2Fapache%2Ftomcat%2Fmaven%2Fplugin%2Ftomcat7%2Frun%2FRunMojo.java#L58). You can try with useTestClasspath = true.

Comment: Tried adding <useTestClasspath>true</useTestClasspath> to plugin configuration section, with scope set to 'test' for IndexFileAccessTracker. Still get ClassNotFoundException.